# Optimize CTE query

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, common-table-expression

I have a big join of 15 tables. Simplified it looks like this

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT A.ID,
         B.K,
         X.Date,
         X.ID,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.ID ORDER BY X.date ASC, x.id ASC) RN
  FROM A
  INNER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID        
  INNER JOIN C ON B.ID = C.ID    
  LEFT JOIN X ON (X.G = A.ID
                 OR X.H = B.ID
                 OR X.I = C.ID)
)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

Execution time is about 1 second mostly because of the last JOIN of `X`. To avoid duplicates I added the `ROW_NUMBER` part and turned it into a CTE.

How could I optimize this preferably using ANSI SQL since it is running on SQL-Server and Oracle?

Comment: Oracle and SQL Server are very different RDBMS; performance can be quite different between the 2.

Comment: Why do you use ROW_NUMBER? Use `SELECT DISTINCT ...` without any CTE.

Comment: Because the result is not distinct

Comment: Is 1 second really that big of a problem?

Comment: @Larnu: It is not that big but still unpleasant.

Comment: Honestly, I would not say 1 second is "unpleasant" if you're dealing with 15 tables and (presumably) millions of rows.

Comment: Yes, maybe. The thing is it ran before in 0.2 seconds and since I fixed the duplicates-bug it slowed down. But maybe that is the time the engine needs to filter that no matter what.

Comment: Minor note: both ANSI SQL and Oracle has `date` as reserved word, so that column name has to be handled. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words

Comment: @jarlh: The actual column name is different but thanks anyway.

Comment: A query cannot be "optimized" when it is not posted completely along with the execution plan. DDL would also be very useful. You partition by A.ID which is the same value as X.G so perhaps you can rearrange the query to push the row numbering down into x?

Comment: @juergend, without knowing how big the tables are is difficult, but 1 second is a really very response time, Obviously, if before was 0.2, the filtering part now is taking time, so you have your explanation. But again, 1 second should not keep you awake, unless this query is executed thousands of times per day.

Comment: @SMor: Didn't change performace but good one. Thanks.

Comment: Depending on your data and indexes, using 3 separate joins *might* help, i.e. `LEFT JOIN X AS x1 ON x1.G = A.ID LEFT JOIN X AS x2 ON x2.H = B.ID LEFT JOIN X AS x3 ON x3.I = C.ID` rather than a single join with `OR` conditions. You'd then have to select the earliest of the 3 records using case expressions (one for ID one for date), and the apply the row_number to that to prevent further duplicates. It will be much more verbose, but often 3 index seeks outperform a single clustered index scan

Comment: We can't answer this without the full query, table *and index* definitions, and a query plan

Comment: As `A.ID = B.ID` and `B.ID = C.ID` are your inner join conditions, couldn't your outer join conditions be rewritten as `A.ID in (X.G, X.H, X.I)`?

Comment: Thanks for all the tipps! I got a solution that is working. See below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it. It is super fast like this (0.1 seconds):

```
  SELECT A.ID,
         B.K,
         X.DATE,
         X.ID,
  FROM A
  INNER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID        
  INNER JOIN C ON B.ID = C.ID    
  LEFT JOIN 
  (
     SELECT G, H, I, ID, DATE,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY G ORDER BY DATE ASC, ID ASC) RN
     FROM X
  ) X ON RN = 1 AND (X.G = A.ID
                     OR X.H = B.ID
                     OR X.I = C.ID)
```